# how to catch the error of execute immediate (open for)?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, procedure

I have this procedure:

```
PROCEDURE proc_with_cursor(  P_PARAM1_IN NUMBER, P_PARAM2_IN NUMBER, P_CURSOR_OUT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    IS
    v_sql   VARCHAR2 (32767);
    v_script   VARCHAR2 (32767);
    v_bind_vars VARCHAR2 (32767);
BEGIN
     v_sql := 'BEGIN OPEN :1 FOR :2 ';
     v_bind_vars := P_PARAM1_IN||', '||P_PARAM2_IN;
     v_sql := v_sql||' USING '||v_bind_vars||'; ';
    --tried also following  but also couldn't catch the error!
    --v_sql := v_sql ||'EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(''error: ''||SQLCODE||'' - ''||SQLERRM); END;';
    v_sql := v_sql||' END;';

    v_script := 'select sysdate from dual where 1= :bind_first and 2 = :bindsecond';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql using P_CURSOR_OUT, v_script;     

    EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('error: '||SQLCODE||' - '||SQLERRM); -- this part is not catching the error!!!!!   
END;
```

Sometimes, the script will throw an error like:

> ORA-12847: retry parsing due to concurrent DDL operation
>
> [Error] Execution (1: 1): ORA-12847: retry parsing due to concurrent DDL operation

My question is: how to catch that error?

Comment: Why do you use `execute immediate` for opening a cursor? Can you please provide a more real code.

Comment: in order to pass a string to USING with bind variables created dynamically  during the procedure

Comment: OPEN P_CURSOR_OUT FOR v_script USING v_bind_vars; will complain about not all variables bound

Comment: If the number of variables is not known at compile time then use [DBMS_SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#i996891)

Comment: is there a way to pass results from dbms_sql cusor to an output refcursor parameter?

Comment: What do you mean by "pass results ... to an **output** parameter"? In principle DBMS_SQL should provide whatever you need.

Comment: by calling the procedure I will display the data directly by showing the cursor! Show me how to collect all data's from DBMS_SQL into an output cursor parameter

Comment: Are you looking for [DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS73893)?

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a look at .. meanwhile - the topic is still open

Answer (score 2):

You cannot bind object **names** (e.g. cursor names) and variable **names** into dynamic SQL, only **values**.  I think this may do what you intend:

```
PROCEDURE proc_with_cursor(  p_param1_in NUMBER, p_param2_in NUMBER, p_cursor_out OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
    v_script   VARCHAR2 (32767);
BEGIN
    v_script := 'select sysdate from dual where 1= :bind_first and 2 = :bindsecond';

    OPEN p_cursor_out FOR v_script USING p_param1_in, p_param2_in;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('error: '||sqlcode||' - '||sqlerrm); 
END;
```

Comment: it's not about names of the objects but the values of! v_bind_vars := P_PARAM1_IN||', '||P_PARAM2_IN; will collect values and will pass them after that to USING, this is for example when you'll have a collection of values that should be passed to a script from clob with a looot of bind variables

Comment: OK I may have misread you on that part.  But you are coding 'BEGIN OPEN :1 FOR :2 ', and that will not work because you cannot bind a value for (1) a cursor variable name, and (2) a query .  You can only bind **values** (like numbers, varchar2s, dates) **used** by the query.

Comment: v_sql will be: BEGIN OPEN :1 FOR :2 USING 1,2; END; And all that will be passed to execute immediate which will do the binding of :1 and :2 with output cursor variable and the value(!) of v_script .  And yes - it will work! The only thing I'm complaining is error handler.

Comment: @tv Oh yes, so it does, my apologies.  I've never seen that done before, is there a reason for writing it this way rather than the much simpler version I posted?  Just curious.

Comment: i need to pass a string as USING , a string that is created on the go based on some if's. If there's another way to bind variables dynamically based on some if rules to the open for then I'm glad to listen. The way you described - it's hardcoded USING parameters which is totally NOTOK for me: when i'll append an additional clause to the v_script - then you'll have to pass the third parameter to using which, simply, will not work!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem. If you have this procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_with_cursor(  p_param1_in NUMBER, p_param2_in NUMBER, p_cursor_out OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
    v_script   VARCHAR2 (32767);
BEGIN
    v_script := 'select sysdate fromM dual where 1= :bind_first and 2 = :bindsecond';
    OPEN p_cursor_out FOR v_script USING p_param1_in, p_param2_in;
END;
```

Then you get this:

```
DECLARE
    cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    proc_with_cursor(1, 2, cur);    
end;
/

Error at line 1
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
ORA-06512: at "xxx.PROC_WITH_CURSOR", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

What else would you like to get? Your (poor) code is working:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_with_cursor(  P_PARAM1_IN NUMBER, P_PARAM2_IN NUMBER, P_CURSOR_OUT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
    v_sql   VARCHAR2 (32767);
    v_script   VARCHAR2 (32767);
    v_bind_vars VARCHAR2 (32767);
BEGIN
    v_sql := 'BEGIN OPEN :1 FOR :2 ';
    v_bind_vars := P_PARAM1_IN||', '||P_PARAM2_IN;
    v_sql := v_sql||' USING '||v_bind_vars||'; ';
    v_sql := v_sql||' END;';

    v_script := 'select sysdate fromm dual where 1= :bind_first and 2 = :bindsecond';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING P_CURSOR_OUT, v_script;     

EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('error: '||SQLCODE||' - '||SQLERRM);   
END;


DECLARE
    cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    proc_with_cursor(1,2, cur);
END;
```

Prints `error: -923 - ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected` on the DBMS_OUTPUT.

If you like to get the exception then do

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_with_cursor(  P_PARAM1_IN NUMBER, P_PARAM2_IN NUMBER, P_CURSOR_OUT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
    v_sql   VARCHAR2 (32767);
    v_script   VARCHAR2 (32767);
    v_bind_vars VARCHAR2 (32767);
BEGIN
    ...    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING P_CURSOR_OUT, v_script;     

EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('error: '||SQLCODE||' - '||SQLERRM);  
        RAISE;  
END;
```

Comment: you're binding parameters to the cursor one by one, one by one while I need to do that as a comma separated string. This means that open for should be executed inside execute immediate which sometimes returns error described in topic (error generated not by the procedure but by the execute immediate functionality itself)

Comment: You cannot bind parameters as a comma separated string (the entire string would be treated as **one** value). Either bind a collection, e.g. `TABLE OF NUMBER` or use the DBMS_SQL package.

Comment: that was discussed upper in comments! YES YOU CAN if there execute immediate with begin-end block!

Comment: But it is the wrong way of doing it. If you pass for example DATE values or text which include single quote `'` then you get problems. It is one of the main purpose of bind variables to avoid such problems.